# Auto rotation of scanned documents using java

Tags: java, image-processing, scanning, autorotate

I'm developing a java application which has document reading using **OCR**.
        The output seems to be incorrect sometimes because of the incorrect orientation of the scanned document. 
        So that I need to autorotate the scanned document. 
        May I know whether the OCR Engine itself has the auto-rotation feature or any other SDK has this feature.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: _May i know whether the OCR Engine itself has the automation feature_ **Which** engine? There are _a lot_ of OCR engines.

Comment: Now i'm using J4L. but i want to change engine if there are ocr engines that support auto-rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [FineReader OCR Software](http://www.abbyy.com.au/finereader/). It is a very useful tool and it has a property called `PageProcessingParams::DetectOrientation` which - if set to `true` - will rotate your image automatically.

Hopefully this helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking the photo handling the Camera API then you could check the sensors in the moment user takes the photo (presses the button).

With that info you could determine the orientation of the device in the moment the photo was taken and then make some rotations.